# Maven Reactor Build Order Print Format

Tags: maven, maven-reactor

I am working on a very large multi module maven project (200+ modules) which has a complicated directory structure. When trying to familiarise myself around the project and its maven modules I am looking closely at the maven reactor build order. However, it would be nice if I could format the output for the Reactor Build Order to contain a bit more information than just the ${project.name} value. Is this possible?

What I can see:

```
[INFO] ProjectParent                 [pom]
[INFO] ProjectSubModuleOne           [jar]
[INFO] ProjectSubModuleTwo           [jar]
[INFO] ProjectSubParentOne           [pom]
[INFO] ProjectSubParentModuleOne     [jar]
[INFO] ...
```

which is effectively

```
[INFO] ${project.name}    [${project.packaging}]
```

What I would like to see is something like:

```
[INFO] ${project.name} - {project.artifactId} - ${project.basedir} [${project.packaging}]
```

which would then resolve to

```
[INFO] ProjectParent - parent - ./pom.xml                          [pom]
[INFO] ProjectSubModuleOne - module-one - module-one/pom.xml       [jar]
[INFO] ProjectSubModuleTwo - module-two - module-two/pom.xml       [jar]
[INFO] ProjectSubParentOne - sub-parent - sub-parent/pom.xml       [pom]
[INFO] ProjectSubParentModuleOne - sub-parent-module-one/pom.xml   [jar]
[INFO] ...
```

This will be particularly helpful for me as the project I am working does not have its directory structure matching the module structure. Also directory names do not always match artifact IDs.

Therefore it would be great if I can change the way the Reactor Build Order is printed in build logs.

Comment: The problem here is not Maven... the poms have defined the `<name>..</name>` tag and not kept the default... If the directory structure does not really represent the structure of the modules etc. or the relationships between levels it should be changed...

Comment: I am not suggesting a problem with Maven. I am hoping to edit the print format of the reactor plugin to help navigate a complicated project structure. Given the maturity of the project, changing the project is not a viable solution especially in the short term

Comment: There is no reactor plugin... you can change the name tags as I mentioned...You can check on a separate branch... to get more insights...

Comment: You could use some simple plugin like the maven echo plugin to output the information you want for all the reactor projects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The more time I spend on the project, I will get used to its 200+ modules. Just have to wait it out on this one